# Ternary Operator Unexpected Result

Tags: c#

Can someone comment on the issue I'm having. A ternary operator throws an error and the argument here is that if it evaluates to null then it should ignore the part after the colon. The Watch set up for this indicates an exception:

```
Int32.Parse(SQLDataReader["TrayId"].ToString())' threw an exception of Type 'System.FormatException
```

suggesting that it can't convert a null to a string. Is this how it works?

```
ShipmentId = SQLDataReader["ShipmentId"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Int32.Parse(SQLDataReader["ShipmentId"].ToString()),
```

Comment: `FormatException` generally mean that it can't parse it as an `int`.

Comment: you should see what you actually get back.

Comment: try just `null` instead of `DBNull.Value`

Comment: "suggesting that it can't convert a null to a string" No. It is saying it cannot convert a `null` to an `int`. You can use `TryParse` to not have the exception.

Comment: @DanielA.White, it returns DBNull. ShipmentId is an int in code, as well as in DB. It comes in a string from test page.

Comment: Could you use [COALESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) in your SQL statement to avoid the problem in the first place?

Comment: @Jonesy, I've tried just null - same result.

Comment: Use `int.TryParse()` to avoid the whole issue and assume some dark magic was involved

Comment: My two cents if you havent done so already, Set a breakpoint here, use a watch1 to see what value you're getting for each of these and then decide if you have to change anything?

Comment: I just totally realized that your error code and your code line don't match up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended that for comparisons with DBNull, you use the DBNull.Value.Equals method, as described on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx

```
ShipmentId = DBNull.Value.Equals(SQLDataReader["ShipmentId"]) ? 0 : Int32.Parse(SQLDataReader["ShipmentId"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had some other issues but ultimatelly your code worked! Have a great day, Nick!

Answer (score 3):

The column `ShipmentId` is an integer, but it is also `nullable`, which means that the c# type is `int?`.

The error boils down to this code:

```
Int32.Parse((string)null)
```

The parsing gives up because you can't turn `null` into an `int`.

To fix this, use `TryParse`.

```
int ShipmentId = 0;
int.TryParse(SQLDataReader["ShipmentId"].ToString(), out ShipmentId);
```

This will cover if the value is `null`, or if for some strange reason the value can't actually be converted to an int (like "asdf121343fds").

Comment: Thanks for your post. I've tried TryParse and it didn't work, but for other reason I think - my columns didn't match, which is my stupid mistake. So by the time I tried @Nick Raverty's suggestion I have discoverd my mismatched columns so it was a matter conrrecting them.

Comment: @Risho, yeah, I noticed 15 minutes after I posted my answer that your error message and your code example used different columns.